# How to skip crop function if the file is uploaded in .pdf format?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

I'm creating a upload multiple file function using JavaScript. And I have problem when user are uploading their file in pdf extensions. Because when user first try to upload the document, if they are uploading picture they will have to crop their picture first then save it before the file got uploaded to the server. But now I got problem if the upload `.pdf` file. How to make the code skip the crop function if user are uploading other than `.jpg ,.jpeg,.png` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `photo` variable you set in the line `let photo  = $(this).prop("files")[0];` is an object of type [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which comes with some properties you can inspect, one of which being `File.type`

Something like the following should work:

```js
let photo  = $(this).prop("files")[0];

if (photo.type !== 'application/pdf') {
  // file isn't a pdf, do the crop logic here
  
  ... cropping logic
}
```